# Config specs and Load rules difference

Tags: clearcase

What is the difference between Config specs and Load rules in Clearcase?

Are both of them edited using "cleartool editcs -tag " command only?

Answer (score 12):

A config spec is a collection of:

- selection rules (for selection the right versions)
- load rules (only for snapshot view) for loading into your "workspace" (the snapshot view) the files selected by... the selection rules just above!

You can edit both with `ct edcs` (just "`ct edcs`" if you are anywhere in a ClearCase view).

Of course, in a dynamic view, you will only edit selection rules, since there are no "load rules":
there is nothing to "*load*" on your disk, since the all point of dynamic view is *network* access to data (very quick, and *dynamic* as in "automatically refreshed" if the selection rule is on "`LATEST`" of a branch).

---

Simple tricks with load rules:

a/ Use "/" even on windows
No need of `load \myVob`: `load /myVob` works too

b/ Use them in combination with "cleaning selection rules":
a selection rule is a rule at the end (before the loading rules) which selections **nothing**

```
 element /myVob/* -none
```

Since other selection rules placed **before** that one does select several sub-directories, that last selection rules only means: "if it is not previously selected before, do NOT select it at all".

Consequence for a snapshot view?

Instead of writing:

```
load /myVob/a
load /myVob/b/b1
load /myVob/b/b2
# do not load /myVob/c
# do not load /myVob/d
load /myVob/e
```

(because you only want specific directories within /myVob), you can just write:

```
load /myVob
```

One simple load rule: it won't load what is not selected. and since "`/myVob/c`" or "`/myVob/d`" are not selected, they will not appear (even empty) on the disk within your snapshot view.

Comment: Clear explanation. Thanks Von!

Would you be able to help me on my other question regarding CC-CQ setup?

Comment: Excellent answer, that'll help us clean up our overly verbose load rules. VonC, please, never get run over by a bus or something! I believe you're the world's only ClearCase guru that is active on SO. ;p

Comment: @antred Thank you. I'll be there. Every day. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309). As for ClearCase guru (less active, but no less impressive), that would be http://stackoverflow.com/users/4223401/brian-cowan or http://stackoverflow.com/users/598141/ian-w.