# How do I create a snapshot view of some project or stream in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

I would like to get contents of some stream or project I can find in clearcase project explorer.

Comment: Cue VonC, the Jon Skeet of ClearCase, in 5...4...3...

Comment: a stream or a project references baselines and activities. In the project explorer, you will not get any files. Only baselines and activities within each streams.

Comment: Ok, how can I then get the files referenced by the stream or project?

Comment: Just added UCM dynamic view option. Could you try to illustrate exactly the kind of content you need to see?

Comment: I tried ClearCase for the first time and I can find some projects with the project explorer. I want to have the latest versions of files and directories on my harddrive.

Comment: I confirm: this is a UCM view that you need st.art with a dynmic UCM view: quickest way to access those data.

Comment: There's a very slow connection to the place where the server lies. How can I do a snapshot view to the same place?

Comment: Just added snapshot view informations.

Comment: the load rules does not deal with stream/project, only vobs and directories. A load rule only need to specify the vob you want to load, whatever the selection rules (based on the stream) are.

Comment: Do not hesitate to add in your question error messages you could have when typing a command. I will debug those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2... 1

```
cleartool descr -l project:myProject@\myPVob
```

with some grep, you have the list of components (writable or not) and policies.

If you want only the Streams:

```
cleartool lsproj -tree myProject@\myPVob
```

You can repeat that for a Stream (to get the sub-streams)

```
cleartool lsstream -tree myStream@\myPVob
```

For the foundation baselines of a Stream:

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[mod_comps]CXp" stream:myStream@\ideapvob
```

For the activities of a Stream:

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[activities]CXp" stream:myStream@\ideapvob
```

---

If you want to consult the files (i.e. the exact version of each files) referenced by a stream, the quickest way would be to create a UCM dynamic view on that stream:

```
 cleartool mkview -tag myView_myStream -stream myStream@\myPVob -stg myStorage
```

With a dynmic view, you will not have any load rule (since it is a *dynamic* view).

You only need to mount the VOB which you want to see

```
cleartool mount \myVob
```

And you can start browsing the files

```
 M:\myView_myStream\myVob\...
```

---

For snapshot view, see "[Proper ‘cleartool mkview’ for ClearCase Snapshot view creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207409/proper-cleartool-mkview-for-clearcase-snapshot-view-creation)"

```
 mkview -snapshot -tag myView_myStream_snap -vws \\mySharedPath\myView_myStream_snap.vws -host myHostname -hpath \\mySharedPath\myView_myStream_snap.vws -gpath \\mySharedPath\myView_myStream_snap.vws myRootDir
```

For the load rules, see:

[Config specs and Load rules difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346966/config-specs-and-load-rules-difference/1346985#1346985)

Comment: I meant with contents that how do I get the files of the stream or project?

Comment: I can get empty directory with mkview command. What should I specify in load rules?

Comment: How can I make a snapshot view of the same thing? The connection is so slow that I can't use dynamic view.

Comment: I can't find any information on how to specify stream/project information in the load rules. I tried with stream:sdlkfj project:sdf \VOB\Project etc.

Comment: I'll just make a new question about that. Thank you very much for your patience VonC :D