# How to specify stream/project in ClearCase snapshot view load rules?

Tags: clearcase

How to specify load rules in this case?

Previously discussed in [How do I create a snapshot view of some project or stream in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367635/how-do-i-create-a-snapshot-view-of-some-project-or-stream-in-clearcase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a UCM snapshot view, you reference the stream at the creation:

```
cleartool mkview -snap -tag myView_myStream_snap -stream myStream@\myPVob -stg myStorge myRootDir
```

Note: "myView_myStream_snap" is a convention of mine for naming a UCM snapshot view using the stream "myStream". You can actually name that snapshot view with whatever naame you want.

The load rules are only there to specify what to load within a snapshot view **whatever the selection rules are** (the "`element ...`" rules which are *before* the load rules)

```
 load /myVob/dirA
 load /myVob/dirB/dirB1
 load /myVob/dirB/dirB2
```

There is no notion of stream or projects here.

- The stream represents the "configuration" (i.e. the list of labels referencing some files)
- The load rules represent what you want to load, without making any assumptions on the exact version selected

The combination of the two (the select rules based on the stream + the load rules) enable you to see the actual files within your newly created snapshot view.