# How to create a view using mkview in clearcase tool?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

How to create a view using the clearcase command mode? How to create it?

mkview -tag mainr2 \\ccaseind\viewstore\mainr2.vws

I even tried these too

mkview -tag mainr2 //ccaseind/viewstore/mainr2.vws

when i execute these command it says unable to create directory followed with unable to create view?What command should i follow? and how to create a view? also tell me the use trigger types, attribute types, html types in Clearcase.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a Windows-style UNC path, so: `\\ccaseind\viewstore\mainr2.vws`

You can see example of dynamic and snapshot view creation in the question "[How do I create a snapshot view of some project or stream in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367635/how-do-i-create-a-snapshot-view-of-some-project-or-stream-in-clearcase)"
(just remove the `-stream` argument which is used by UCM)

For a snapshot view, in your case, you are missing a `-vws` in front of the shared path.

Comment: but its not working Von please help me \\ccaseind\viewstore\mainr2.vws its not workin

Comment: @cody  I am in the middle of meetings right now, I will contact you later today or tomorrow

Comment: @cody: ... and back. Please join me in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1204/clearcase