# Why Clearcase mkelem infinitely waits in windows?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I am trying to add a file to Clearcase via Cleartool command.

I have executed the following command into my "cmd"

```
C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop>cleartool mkelem "Z:\MyApplication\Impl\DataModels\Model\Build.Model.ps1"
Creation comments for "Z:\MyApplication\Impl\DataModels\Model\Build.Model.ps1":
```

It is infinitely waits without doing anything. If i do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it says interrupted.

What am i missing?

Update:

I have tried with cleartool mkelem -c "some useful comment" option also. but still fails. As instructed by @VonC i have even run the same command in Snapshot view but no luck.

Comment: As far as I can remember, Clearcase suffers of "ghost file": You can't recreate a file previously deleted. Maybe something linked with that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try at least to:

- set the comment in the [`cleartool mkelem`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkelem.htm) call itself:

  ```
  cleartool mkelem -c "..."
  ```
- check if the parent folder is checked out.
- check if there is a pre or post-op trigger on element creation, as mentioned in [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013699634).
  Maybe the script associated with that trigger has an issue and freezes the all process.

Comment: Still the issue exist. It was waiting infinitely with the line. Creation comments for "Z:\Myfolder\Build.ps1". When i click Ctrl+C it show as .  cleartool: Warning: Moved private data from "Z:\Myfolder\Build.ps1" to "Z:\Myfolder\Build.ps1.mkelem" during element creation; unable to move it back: File exists.

Interrupt

Comment: @Samselvaprabu try to execute that same command directly in the full path of the view (instead of `Z:\`. Type `subst`, to see what `Z:` is for, then go to that path, and from there go to the parent folder of the element you are trying to create)

Comment: it is dynamic view. I have tried with going to original view path in M: drive but still facing the same issue. Is there issue in windows OS for clearcase?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu Can you check if the issue persists in a snapshot view (that you would create with the same config spec as the dynamic one)

Comment: i am using UCM. any how i will try to do

Comment: @Samselvaprabu simply create a snapshot viewusing the same stream as you dynamic view: follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/1367656/6309.

Comment: No luck with snapshot view too

Comment: What ClearCase are you using? On which OS? What is the OS of the ClearCase server?

Answer (score 0):

As it looks to be waiting for a comment...

Cleartool, when it prompts for a comment, needs a period on a line by itself to complete the comment prompt. This allows cleartool to acccept multi-line comments.