# using a snapshot view based on a dynamic view

Tags: clearcase

I already have a dynamic view created for me. Ideally, what I would have liked instead is a snapshot view with the exact same config spec.
I have two questions in that regard:

1. do I have to create a separate snapshot view (with a different tag name) or can I piggy-back on top of the dynamic view to create a snapshot on my local disk? (without using `mkview` again).
2. if I do need to run a separate `mkview` to create the snapshot view, would I have to provide the `mkview -sna` with a different `-tag`, `-hpa`,  `-gpa` and a different `snapshot-view-pname` ?
3. would it be transparent to my co-developers whether I am working in a snapshot versus a dynamic view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I have to create a separate snapshot view (with a different tag name) or can I piggy-back on top of the dynamic view to create a snapshot on my local disk?

No: you need to use [`mkview` (`-snap`)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm) again, in order to create a separate view, a snapshot one with a root folder on your disk.

See "[Proper 'cleartool mkview' for ClearCase Snapshot view creation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207516/6309)", assuming we are talking about a base ClearCase view, not an UCM one.

But then you can re-use the same *config spec*, at least the selection rules part (since a snapshot view has loading rules specific to its nature, a dynamic view having no need for loading anything: see "[Config specs and Load rules difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1346985/6309)").
You can copy them from a `cleartool catcs -tag <dyn-view-tag>`, and paste them in a `cleartool edcs -tag <snap-view-tag>` (best done from within the root folder of the snapshot view).
(an UCM view, snapshot or dynamic, would not need that, as it would be created with `-stream`, getting the right selection rules based on the foundation baselines of that associated stream)

> would I have to provide the `mkview -sna` with a different `-tag`, `-hpa`, `-gpa` and a different `snapshot-view-pname`?

The tag would be different for sure, `hpa` (host storage pathname) and `gpa` (global storage pathname) also in that they would end with `<tag-name.vws>`, the view storage folder named after your new view tag name.

> would it be transparent to my co-developers whether I am working in a snapshot versus a dynamic view?

Yes: when you finally check in a file (in a dynamic or snapshot view), your collaborators would see that check in at the same time.
However, if your collaborators are themselves checking in some files, you would not see those updated version (assuming you are working on the same branch) until you [`cleartool update`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm) your own snapshot view.

Comment: `However, if your collaborators are themselves checking in some files, you would not see those ...` that's what I am expecting consistent with the way someone works in Git or SVN.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus more SVN than Git though: a `git fetch` is needed indeed, but that is because the repo is distributed, and all operations are done locally (beside fetch, pull, push or clone).

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus For more about the differences between ClearCase and Git: http://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309. And for more about a CVCS (centralized VCS) workflow and a DVCS one (Distributed): http://stackoverflow.com/q/2704996/6309

Comment: Small quibble. setcs -tag doesn't work reliably for a snapshot view. It's best to CD into the snapshot view's workspace and run cleartool setcs from there.

Another note: if the dynamic view is UCM, don't use setcs, make the vview with -stream instead. You can get weird behavior if you set a non-UCM view to a UCM configspec.

Comment: @BrianCowan yes, I did not mention -stream because the OP seems to be working with base ClearCase only. I'll edit the answer for the rest. Note: I used edcs, not setcs (but both should be best executed from within the snpashot view, making sure to trigger an update)